# Desenhar rota em cima da rua no mapa

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Tenho uma funcionalidade que capta as posições do `gps` a cada 10 segundos.

A cada 30 segundos ou se há uma mudança de 20 graus no [bearing](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getBearing()) (Comparo a última posição com a atual) armazeno para enviar ao serviço.

Após, o usuário pode visualizar a rota!

Desenho a rota através de um `Polyline` , e como o tempo de captação das posições é meio grande (pensando no consumo da bateria) ela fica desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma forma de *suavizar* o desenho da rota?

Ou há como desenhar o `Polyline` sobre a rua?

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Para que a *polyline* possa ser mais suave tem de usar mais pontos.

Comment: Então meu medo é acabar com o plano de dados do usuário, sem contar a bateria que vai drenar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para criar um  aplicativo simples que encontra rotas entre dois lugares baseado no endereço no Mapa do Google, você pode usar [Google Map Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro?hl=pt-br).

> A Google Maps Directions API é um serviço que calcula rotas entre
> locais usando uma solicitação HTTP.

Uma solicitação da Google Maps Directions API tem o seguinte formato:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/output?parameters
```

onde output pode ser um dos seguintes valores:

- json (recomendado) indica a saída em JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)
- xml indica a saída como XML

Para acessar a Google Maps Directions API por HTTP, use:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/output?parameters
```

No Github tem um projeto onde você pode iniciar sua aplicação: **GoogleMapDirectionSimple** [Create a simple app that find a path between two places](https://github.com/hiepxuan2008/GoogleMapDirectionSimple/).

#### Screenshots

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Atualização

O Google fez uma mudança nas diretivas em relação aos termos de uso. Agora para poder usar seus serviços de API do Google Maps, é necessário inserir o chave na URL. Veja como [obter uma chave/autenticação](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=pt-br).

Por exemplo, que deseja sair da São Paulo e ir para Curitiba, deves fazer desta forma:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Sao+Paulo&destination=Curitiba&&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Veja aqui os [**primeiros passos**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start?hl=pt-br) para o uso do serviço.

#### Detalhes

- [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?hl=pt-br)
- [Mapas e inovadores de locais](https://developers.google.com/maps/?hl=pt-br)

Comment: Obrigado @seamusd, vou pesquisar e valido sua resposta!

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski Opa! Qualquer coisa, faça suas observações e vamos tentar resolver juntos! Abraços.